# Umbraco - accessing a Node without the full structure in the URL

Tags: umbraco

in Umbraco I have a link:

```
/living/travel/2012/december/costa-del-christmas/
```

Is it possible to access it by removing the dates 2012/december? The URL would result in the following:

/living/travel/costa-del-christmas/

At the moment I get a 404 error when doing this.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use the umbracoUrlAlias method.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlalias

Add a new property to your DocumentType with an alias of umbracoUrlAlias and make it a text string type.  Then on the content you can assign any alternate url to that content and they will resolve to the same page.

You may want to add some meta information to deal with canonical links as well so Google doesn't think you have duplicate content.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Thanks! 

Off topic: I haven't seen you around on Twitter, but I'd love to see you join the N. American Umbraco Users Group (http://nauug.com)

Comment: This looks like an OK solution but there are thousands of pages, so I would like it to be automated as opposed to typing in the URL each time a page is created.

Comment: @Funky, you could set the umbracoUrlAlias programmatically in the before publish event, or any event for that matter - see http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events.